# Cannot get the Unity web player to load the Facebook dll

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to test my Facebook integration for a FB Canvas game that I'm working on. When I launch the player I see the following message in the console:

`loading dll: /rsrc/unity/lib/sdk_5.0/CanvasFacebook.dll
  Failed downloading /rsrc/unity/lib/sdk_5.0/CanvasFacebook.dll`

and if I look in the apache logs I see a request for `/rsrc/unity/lib/sdk_5.0/CanvasFacebook.dll`

I have the same problem using the 4.3.x version of the Facebook SDK.

I'm using Unity editor 4.3 and testing in Chrome on OSX.

Am I missing a DLL or a reference in MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you hit build and run for the Unity webplayer.  This launches your game in a web browser hosted off your local filesystem.  For security purposes, the SDK must be running on Facebook canvas when run in a web browser.  You'll need to set up a Facebook app, instructions are here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity
Alternatively, you can test in the Unity editor by hitting the play button.

Comment: Is it possible to get the Facebook SDK to work via the Unity editor? I can't seem to get it to auth.

Comment: Yes, if you have your app configured correctly on developer.facebook.com you can login and use the sdk in the unity editor.