# Facebook SDK working in Editor, but not when I upload it to my Server

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am using the Facebook Sdk 5.0.3 Beta for a test proyect I'm working on Unity.

When I run my game in the editor, I can login, post to my feed, all without a problem. But I'm having trouble to deploy it to my server. I upload the output of the webplayer into my website, and when I go to play the game, nothing is happening when I click on the Facebook functionality...

Am I missing some steps here? Some key? I see in the website that there is an App Token... Maybe thats it?

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to host the game on your own website.  Facebook integration over the web will only work if your game is hosted by Facebook.  This is related to this question: [Cannot get the Unity web player to load the Facebook dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646590/cannot-get-the-unity-web-player-to-load-the-facebook-dll)